# Angular mat-icon is being "translated"?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-material, angular-i18n

**Summary**: I am using the "+" sign material icon on a page to represent adding a new item.

On the English version of the site, it displays fine. On the Spanish version of the site, it displays "ñ"

**Question**: Should I not have any text in between the tags? Or should I not put a translation element at all?

I tried looking into this but couldn't find anything through SO or google, I also did not see it on the documentation page: https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview

```
<mat-icon (click)="doStuff()" i18n="@@AaBBCcDd_Y2_14">add</mat-icon>
```

**Expected**: To keep the "+" sign in both English and Spanish versions of sites.

**Actual**: Translating to "ñ"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be translating the inner text of `mat-icon`. That text tells MatIcon which icon to load from the icon font - it is like a key. The icon is the same in all languages.